# Dicas de hospedagem para aplicação Java usando JSP, Hibernate, Mysql e TomCat que serve dados para aplicação Android

Tags: java, hospedagem

Galera , é o seguinte. Desenvolvi um aplicativo Android onde ele é alimentado com dados vindos de um banco de dados(Mysql) remoto, via RestFul.

Do lado do servidor, desenvolvi uma aplicação java usando JSP e Hibernate, bando de dados MySql, rodando no TomCat. Esta aplicação é basicamente um backend para que eu possa gerenciar os dados que alimentam e que vem do aplicativo Android.

Esta é a primeira vez que faço algo do tipo, e tudo esta rodando bem no meu servidor local. Só que chegou a hora de contratar um serviço de hospedagem Java e realmente não sei o que seria ideal para começar um close beta do meu aplicativo. Há, lembrando que através do Aplicativo Android, os usuários são capazes de enviar fotos para o servidor, além de enviar alguns dados e consumir dados e imagens vindas do servidor.

Vi alguns planos, em serviços de empresas que me parecem confiáveis:

- [KingHost](http://www.kinghost.com.br/plano-java)
- [UOL](http://www.uolhost.uol.com.br/lp/hospedagem-java.html)
- [brasilwork](https://brasilwork.com.br/hospedagem-de-sites-java-brasil/)

Existe também o serviço de nuvem [elástica Jelastic](http://www.locaweb.com.br/cloud/jelastic/), da Localweb.

Bom, sei que para funcionar a minha aplicação java que serve como backend, preciso do TomCat 7+, do Mysql e Java 7+. Até ai tudo bem. Mas em relação a memoria dos planos? 256MB, 512MB. O vocês sugerem para o meu cenário? 5GB de armazenamento é o suficiente?Ou talvez 10GB ? Este serviços de hospedagem acima são bons? Gostaria de uma hospedagem boa e barata.

Outra coisa importante. Estou usando Autenticação BASIC, então creio que seja necessário pelomenos SSL (https) compartilhado, certo?

desde já, obrigado galera =)

Comment: Nenhuma dessas. Até onde eu conheço, esses serviços brasileiros são bastante limitados ou tem recursos compartilhados. OpenShift, DigitalOcean, AWS ou outro serviço cloud são infinitamente melhores para aplicações e você possui controle total dos servidores. O OpenShift permite você ter 3 instâncias gratuitamente.

Comment: Mas todas estes serviços  Cloud, eu que ficaria responsável por instalar as ferramentas que necessito, como TomCat, Mysql, Java e etc, certo?

Comment: Tem para todos os gostos. O Openshift oferece stacks completos para os tipos mais comuns de sistemas, então é tudo automático. Porém, mesmo na Amazon ou no Digital Ocean você pode colocar imagens prontas com as tecnologias que você quer. Muita gente acha que usar um serviço desses dá mais trabalho porque você provavelmente vai ter se preocupar com um mínimo de configuração, mas um host limitado não é melhor só porque tem um painel de controle bonitinho, quando tem. Vale mesmo a pena ter um serviço mais limitado para evitar ter que aprender instalar um ou dois aplicativos?

Comment: Concordo plenamente com você. Estou tentando fazer o deploy para o OpenShift usando o plugin jBoss Tools para o eclipse, e estou levando uma surra^^.

Comment: Estranho, esse plugin funcionava tão bem quando usei ele num projeto. Sugiro você criar uma pergunta sobre isso.

Comment: Na verdade, consegui enviar meu app pro openshift, adicionei o cartucho do tomcat 7 e do MySql (criei e importei a bade se dados), mas quando acesso o endereço do meu aplicativo no painel do openshift aparece a tela de Welcome padrão, como se não tivesse aplicação nenhuma. Será que estou deixando passar alguma 'manhã' nas configurações do hibernate ou tomcat antes de fazer o deploy??

Comment: Use o plugin para ver os logs da aplicação. Ele permite inclusive acompanhar o log quase em tempo real. Não lembro exatamente o nome da opção, m as isso vai ajudar a identificar problemas na inicialização. Eu lembro que deu algum trabalho configurar as credenciais do banco na época, pois ele gera elas uma vez e se você perder dá um trabalho para recuperar.

Comment: Achei o log, e aparentemente parece tudo bem. O Deploy parece ter sido feito com sucesso, mas quando tento acessar-lo(http://easysurf-sthiago.rhcloud.com/) continua trazendo a pagina de boas vindas do openshift

Comment: Tentou colocar `/meuApp`? Pode ser que falte o contexto.

Comment: Veja isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVtlfxbah5w